# Covert array to array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if there is a way to do this

there is a way to transform this
`` `["frontalCard","backCard"]` ``
to
`` `[{"frontalCard": false},{"backCard": false}]` ``

Comment: Yes there is. Using `map` you can iterate over each item and return an object with the key and the value false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do it with code like this using the Array `map` function

```js
let x = ["frontalCard","backCard"]
let y = x.map(a => ({ [a]: false }))
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
stringArray.map(s => {
  const o = {};
  o[s] = false;
  return o;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30473744)

Comment: @MahmutEFE Please pay attention when reviewing, this is not a "link-only" answer. It is an answer. Due to the lack of information it might be downvote-worthy, but it is still an answer.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I was confused since there was not a single link in my answer.